# Windows media foundation - 'MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL' identifier not found

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am getting few errors while building Windows media foundation application.

`error C3861: 'MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL': identifier not found`
`error C2027: use of undefined type 'IMFSourceReader'`

I have added Additional Include Directory and Library file paths in the project properties. I have also added "mfplat.lib" as additional dependencies.

But still I am getting above errors.

Comment: Check the windows version (WINVER) in your stdafx.h. It should be higher than _WIN32_WINNT_VISTA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

Comment: `#include <mfreadwrite.h>` as MSDN suggests. You are supposed to post code here, it's a beginner's problem and you don't want others guess what you did wrong.

Comment: @RomanR. is right.  In addition, which version of VS are you using?